# SWIG - Rename structure members

Tags: java, swig

I am trying to use the %rename feature of SWIG to rename multiple members of a C++ struct to Java.

This is my **SActivityType.h**:

```
struct SActivityType
{
    unsigned int m_uActivityType;
    unsigned int m_uActivityId;
};
```

This is a working **project.i**:

```
%rename("%(strip:[m_u])s") MY_NAMESPACE::SActivityType::m_uActivityType;
%rename("%(strip:[m_u])s") MY_NAMESPACE::SActivityType::m_uActivityId;
%include "SActivityType.h"
```

But instead of specifying all the members, I tried to do something like:

```
%rename("%(strip:[m_u])s") "MY_NAMESPACE::SActivityType::m_u*";
%include "SActivityType.h"
```

or

```
%rename("%(strip:[m_u])s") MY_NAMESPACE::SActivityType;
%include "SActivityType.h"
```

But none is working, the getter/setters are back to  **setM_uActivityType/getM_uActivityType** in the generated Java.

So is there a way to tell SWIG to rename all matching members in a single declaration?